# Using Beautiful Soup4 can I get the <a> embedded text?

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am using Beautiful Soup4 with Python and now any way i have come upto the below. So now in what way I can get the values Dog,Cat, Horse and also the Ids. Please help!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
soup.find_all('a')

# [<a class="Animal" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Dog</a>,
#  <a class="Animal" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Cat</a>,
#  <a class="Animal" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Horse</a>]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes)

```
for a in soup.find_all('a'):
    id = a.get('id')
    value = a.string # This is a NavigableString
    unicode_value = unicode(value)
```

Comment: why you used `unicode(value)`? If you don't what the `value` would get into it! just to clear my understanding! please help!

Comment: To be honest, I only did it because the documentation mentions it as well :)
"A NavigableString is just like a Python Unicode string, except that it also supports some of the features described in Navigating the tree and Searching the tree. You can convert a NavigableString to a Unicode string with unicode()"